# A question about direct product of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

> Let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. Suppose that $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H\simeq K$. My question is when $G\simeq H\times K$?

My guess is if $K$ is normal in $G$ and $G=HK$ then $G\simeq H\times K$. I want to know whether my guess is right. I do not need any proof, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to say something also about $H\cap K$.  This falls under the aegis of "internal direct products".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need these conditions:

$1.)$ $G=HK$

$2.)$ $H$ and $K$ normal in $G$.

$3.)$ $H \cap K= \{1\}$

Then $G=HK \cong H \times K$

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ are infinite, does then the conclusion fails to hold?

Comment: It applies to any normal subgroups where the conditions hold. If $G$ is infinite, then $H$ and $K$ must be infinite.

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ are infinite, then the condition $(4)$ need not to hold. Is that right?

Comment: You don't need 4) at all.

Comment: @DerekHolt Edited

Answer (score 0):

For finite groups, your guess is correct; not sure about the infinite case. For a proof, let $G = HK$, suppose that $H \unlhd G$, $K \unlhd G$, and that $G/H \cong K$. To show that $G\cong H \times K$, we need only show that $H \cap K =1$. We appeal to the diamond isomorphism theorem, which says in this case that $G/H=HK/H \cong K/H \cap K$. But since $G/H \cong K$, we have $K \cong K/H \cap K$, so by order considerations, we must have $H \cap K = 1$.